# Cordova nodejs routing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, routes

I am new to cordova.

I am trying to build cordova app with nodejs as a backend. When I run the app using **browser (cordova run browser)** it is redirecting me to http://localhost:8000/index.html which is fine.

My issue is, when I logged in to the website the browser redirects to "http://localhost:8000/home" and gives not found error. I have set the routing from routes.js to "/home" (nodejs backend).

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: post the code..

Answer (score 0):

did you have something for routing the view like

```
router.addRoute('name of view',function(){'your code here'})
```

Comment: > On server side: **nodejs** (routes.js)  
`app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  if(login.auth(req, res))
   res.redirect(host+':8080/home');
  else
   res.render('index.html');
 });
 app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
  if(login.auth(req, res))
   res.render('home.html');
  else
   res.redirect(host+':8080/login');
});`  
No routing done on **cordova app**. Do I have to do routing on cordova app too?